# How would I use Python to access Google Sheets in a similar manner to the tidyverse googlesheets4 package in R?

Tags: python, r, google-sheets

I'm wondering if there is a Python equivalent of a package in R that makes interacting with Google Sheets very simple. In R I can run `library("googlesheets4")` and `sheet_as_df <- read_sheet(sheet_path, sheet = "sheet_name", skip = 0)`. This prompts a dialogue to authorize tidyverse edit access to sheets. I click authorize on the dialogue box, and then the target sheet is read into R as a data frame. After that initial authorization, I can also read and write to Google Sheets without needing to re-authorize.

I want to do the same thing in Python, but all the methods I have found thus far are much more verbose. What I have found recommends going to Google Developer's Console, creating a project, enabling Google API on that project, creating a service account and granting that service account editor permission, generating json credentials, storing the credentials locally, and reading the credentials into Python. After all that, I *should* be able to access Google Sheets. Is there a way to do this with fewer steps and less code, considering R can connect to Google Sheets via Google API in less than 1 line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.read_csv()` by inputting the URL:

```
import pandas as pd

sheet_id = “1XqOtPkiE_Q0dfGSoyxrH730RkwrTczcRbDeJJpqRByQ”
sheet_name = “sample_1”

url = f”https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}"
pd.read_csv(url)
```

Reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/read-data-from-google-sheets-into-pandas-without-the-google-sheets-api-5c468536550

Comment: The issue I'm having with that solution is that the Google Sheets file needs to be set to the sharing option which allows everyone with the link to view the data, but I want to keep the sheet restricted with myself as the owner and only one with access.